# Interpretation of the results of the Elbow and K-means

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, preprocessing, k-means, algorithms

I have the following dataset (after scaling) which contains 5 features:

[image]:

My objective is to cluster this data using an unsupervised ML model.

After using the Elbow method, I get 2 clusters as below:

[image]

After performing the k-means algorithm I get this weird representation which I think it is due to the sex feature (M or F, 0 or 1).

[image]

I tried to reclustering the data without the sex feature, (finding almost 6 clusters using Silhoulette and Elbow methods) but I can not understand the data representation !

[image]

[image]

The data in the two cases does not seem to have any sense, especially after removing the sex attribute. Also, I wonder if it is normal to have 6 clusters for only 4 features. Or should I try another clustering algorithm other than K-means or adding other preprocessing data method ?  Also, is there any solution to do clustering while keeping the sex attribute (generally a binary attribute)

Any information or general proposition could help !

Thank you in advance.